# Reduce the runtime/execeution on import function for Googlesheets and GoogleApps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Currently have a script that pulls CSV files from google drive from a cell reference.  Just wondering if there's a way to reduce the runtime.  Currently the script takes about 45 -60 seconds to finish running.  Any help would be appreciated or completely alternative way to get a faster response in such where when I change the cell references my data gets pulled faster.

```
function importCSV() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const id = ss.getSheetByName("Dashboard").getRange("A2").getValue();
  const folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(id);
  const name = ss.getSheetByName("Dashboard").getRange("B2").getValue();
  const name2 = ss.getSheetByName("Dashboard").getRange("C2").getValue();
  const file = folder.getFilesByName(name).next();
  const file2 = folder.getFilesByName(name2).next();
  const csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(file.getBlob().getDataAsString());
  const csvData2 = Utilities.parseCsv(file2.getBlob().getDataAsString());
  
  const target = ss.getSheetByName("Input");
  const target2 = ss.getSheetByName("Input2");

  target.getRange(1, 1, csvData.length, csvData[0].length).setValues(csvData);
  target2.getRange(1, 1, csvData2.length, csvData2[0].length).setValues(csvData2);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to reduce the process cost of your script.

#### Modification points:

- `id`, `name` and `name2` can be retrieved by one call.
- In order to put the CSV data by parsing the string data to Spreadsheet, when Sheets API is used, the process cost can be reduced. [Ref](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/030203c695b308606041587e6da269e7) And also, several CSV data can be put to each sheet by one API call.

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

Before you use this script, [please enable Sheets API at Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enable_advanced_services).

```
function importCSV() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const dstSheets = ["Input", "Input2"];
  const [id, ...filenames] = ss.getSheetByName("Dashboard").getRange("A2:C2").getValues()[0];
  const folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(id);
  const obj = filenames.map((f, i) => ({dst: ss.getSheetByName(dstSheets[i]).getSheetId(), data: folder.getFilesByName(f).next().getBlob().getDataAsString()}));
  var resource = {requests: obj.map(({dst, data}) => ({pasteData: {data: data, coordinate: { sheetId: dst }, delimiter: ","}}))};
  Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate(resource, ss.getId());
}
```

- In this script, 2 CSV data of filenames retrieved from the cells "B2" and "C2" are put to the sheet "Input" and "Input2", respectively.

#### References:

- [Benchmark: Importing CSV Data to Spreadsheet using Google Apps Script](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/030203c695b308606041587e6da269e7)
- [Method: spreadsheets.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate)
- [PasteDataRequest](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#pastedatarequest)